# Replacing Constants with Unary Functions

Tags: first-order-logic, universal-algebra, algebraic-logic

Suppose I have a first order theory over some signature $\Sigma$ with constant symbols.

Is there a name for the theory I obtain by replacing the constant symbols with unary function symbols along with axioms that make them behave like constants?

For example, if I look at the theory of groups over signature $(2,1,0)$, there is a corresponding theory with signature $(2,1,1)$, where the new function symbol acts as if it sends everything to the (now not explicitly specified) identity element. Without being too specific about the formalism, has this structure been studied independently in any form?

Comment: I don't know if this exact thing has been specifically studied. But constant symbols and 0-ary function symbols are naturally interchangeable (and this makes sense at the level of signatures--without needing a theory or any axioms). With this viewpoint, what you've done is analogous to replacing every unary function with a binary function, along with axioms saying that the binary function only depends on one coordinate.

Comment: @Gabe obviously I've left things vague, but I'm not asking for an axiom that literally says the function *is* a constant. A lack of constant symbols means that the empty set is a valid set theoretic model of the modified theory, but it certainly is not a group.